# Scrapy custom pipeline outputting files half the size expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm trying to create a custom pipeline for a `Scrapy` project that outputs the collected items to CSV files. In order to keep each file's size down I want to set a maximum number of rows that each file can have. Once the line limit has been reached in the current file a new file is created to continue outputting the items.

Luckily, I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21009027/2962937) where someone was looking to do the same thing. And there's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654790/2962937) to that question that shows an example implementation.

I implemented the example implementation, but tweaked the way `stats` were accessed to align with the current version of `Scrapy`.

## My current code

```
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
import datetime

class PartitionedCsvPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats
        self.stats.set_value('item_scraped_count', 0)
        self.base_filename = "site_{}.csv"
        self.next_split = self.split_limit = 100
        self.create_exporter()  

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.stats)

    def create_exporter(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        datetime_stamp = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
        self.file = open(self.base_filename.format(datetime_stamp),'w+b')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()       

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if self.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count') >= self.next_split:
            self.next_split += self.split_limit
            self.exporter.finish_exporting()
            self.file.close()
            self.create_exporter()
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        self.stats.inc_value('item_scraped_count')
        return item
```

## The Problem

The pipeline does result in multiple files being output, but the files all have only 50 items instead of the 100 that's expected.

## The Question

What am I doing wrong that's making the files half the size that's expected?

Comment: why do you use `item_scraped_count` for this ? Maybe it counts other scraped elements? Maybe you should use `self.count` in `PartitionedCsvPipeline` for this.

Comment: OR maybe you shouldn't increase `item_scraped_count` because `scrapy` already count this element and using `inc_value('item_scraped_count')`  you count it second time and after 50 items `item_scraped_count` has value `100`. BTW: you could use `print()` to see this value before processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in `process_item()`  I add

```
 print('>>> stat count:', self.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count'))
```

and remove

```
 self.stats.inc_value('item_scraped_count')
```

then I see it still increases this variable.

It means other code already counts scraped values so you shouldn't increase it.

If I keep `inc_value()` then I see it counts all elements two times.

---

I'm not sure if it counts only elements which you add to CSV so you could use separated variable to count it

```
class PartitionedCsvPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.count = 0

        # ... code ...
 
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print('>>> count:', self.count)

    if self.count >= self.next_split:
        # ... code ...

    # ... code ...

    self.count += 1

    return item
```

---

**EDIT:**

Pipeline needs this method to close last file and save all data in this file.

```
def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.file.close()
```

---

Minimal working example.

I put all in one file and it can be run `python script.py` without creating project. This way everyone can easily test it.

Because I scrape 10 items in every file so it created new file so fast that I had to add microseconds (`%f`) to filename to create unique names.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
import datetime

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    # see page created for scraping: http://toscrape.com/
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/'] #'http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        # download images and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
        for url in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield {'image_urls': [url], 'session_path': 'hello_world'}


class PartitionedCsvPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.filename = "site_{}.csv"
        self.split_limit = 10
        
        self.count = 0
        self.create_exporter()  

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.stats)

    def create_exporter(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        datetime_stamp = now.strftime("%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S.%f")  # %f for microseconds because sometimes it can create next file in less then 1 second and create the same name.
        
        self.file = open(self.filename.format(datetime_stamp), 'w+b')
        
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()       

    def finish_exporter(self):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
    
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        if self.count >= self.split_limit:
            self.finish_exporter()
            self.count = 0
            self.create_exporter()

        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        self.count += 1
        print('self.count:', self.count)

        return item
        
    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.finish_exporter()
        
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.PartitionedCsvPipeline': 1},   # used Pipeline create in current file (needs __main___)
})

c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that stat value was automatically incremented.

Comment: I tested my code and it seems it counts scraped items even without using pipeline - so I use `self.count` to count items. But I found other problem: pipeline needs method `close_spider()` to close last file and save data in last file. Without this it didn't save data in last file. I put my working code so everyone can easily test it. Later I put it on GitHub with [other examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/scrapy)