# Scrapy Splash, How to deal with onclick?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape the following [site](http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/base.jsp?tableId=27&tableName=TABLE27&title=%E8%BF%9B%E5%8F%A3%E5%8C%BB%E7%96%97%E5%99%A8%E6%A2%B0%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81%EF%BC%88%E6%B3%A8%E5%86%8C&bcId=152904442584853439006654836900)

I'm able to receive a response but i don't know how can i access the inner data of the below items in order to scrape it:

I noticed that accessing the items is actually handled by JavaScript and also the pagination.

What should i do in such case?

[image]

Below is my code:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class NmpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nmpa'
    http_user = 'hidden' # as am using Cloud Splash
    allowed_domains = ['nmpa.gov.cn']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest('http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/base.jsp?tableId=27&tableName=TABLE27&title=%E8%BF%9B%E5%8F%A3%E5%8C%BB%E7%96%97%E5%99%A8%E6%A2%B0%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81%EF%BC%88%E6%B3%A8%E5%86%8C&bcId=152904442584853439006654836900', args={
            'wait': 5}
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        goal = response.xpath("//*[@id='content']//a/@href").getall()
        print(goal)
```

Comment: I'm not a scrapy expert but this section of scrapy's document may help https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Thanks, it's away from the main issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use some breakpoints you'll see its a frustrating job that I explain what I understood from my research.
when you are working with this kind of situation you have two ways:

1 - [**Easy Way**] use selenium and open a browser and click on each link and get the returned contents easily, you can run multiple browsers and get link contents simultaneously.

2 - [**Hard Way**] simulate what website does (by making similar functions inside python) and do exactly what website does in JS but in the end instead of showing the results, just save it in a variable and use it the way you want.

Now if you choose the **HARD WAY** this is what I found:

the link JS is like this:

```
commitForECMA(callbackC,'content.jsp?tableId=26&amp;tableName=TABLE26&amp;tableView=国产医疗器械产品（注册&amp;Id=138150',null)
```

it calls a function named `commitForECMA` and get what this function returns and pass it to `callBackC` function.

well this was obvious, but its important to know what these functions do and how to replicate it.

- **commitForECMA:**

this is the function:

```
function commitForECMA($_8, $_10, $_12) {
    request = createXMLHttp();
    request.onreadystatechange = $_8;
    if ($_12 == null) {
        _$du(request, _$Fe('uM6r2MG'), _$Fe("jp0YV"), $_10);
        request.setRequestHeader(_$Fe("XACeXwDYXwcTV8Ur2"), _$Fe("YwDYgwceLwDT7iCYX3Ce9FKyvHKwPFa"));
    } else {
        var $_9 = "";
        var $_19 = $_12.elements;
        var $_0 = $_19.length;
        for (var $_18 = 0; $_18 < $_0; $_18++) {
            var $_14 = _$3P($_19, $_18);
            if ($_14.type != _$Fe("yQ6YPMK20") && _$3P($_14, _$Fe('uwbm7wKV')) != "") {
                if ($_9.length > 0) {
                    $_9 += "&" + $_14.name + "=" + _$3P($_14, _$Fe('kwbm7wKV'));
                } else {
                    $_9 += $_14.name + "=" + _$3P($_14, _$Fe('Ewbm7wKV'));
                }
                $_9 += _$Fe("Jx2J03Up2Hsl");
            }
        }
        _$du(request, _$Fe('uM6r2MG'), _$Fe("HVlesYq"), $_10);
        $_9 = encodeURI($_9);
        $_9 = encodeURI($_9);
        request.setRequestHeader(_$Fe("d3CmOFDVz3CeXwoxBMq"), _$Fe("FMbZz3CmOFDV"));
        request.setRequestHeader(_$Fe("yACeXwDYXwcTV8Ur2"), _$Fe("g3UraMD2O3UpNMCgB8cT6w6QzRbenM1TTQbS2MbJBRDY9"));
    }
    request.send($_9);
    if ($_12 != null) {
        $_12.reset();
    }
}
```

yes as you can see it just creates a `XMLHTTP` request which (for the links in question) Posts the `$_10` content to the server and get the results in `callBackC` function which is now in `$_8`. but the trick here is the `$_10` contents goes through ~13000 lines of code to create links like this:

```
http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/content.jsp?6SQk6G2z=GBK-56.it.xmhx8IaDT25ZyaSxljrwULe8AkNw8QjmeNqdT0YqZYbMZ2P6Jgn3ZUIgh3ibPI81bjA6xUCKJmzy1LD.4AZnk4g4G_iMO4tdiebiVDoPPtdVDIkDWw0OnDHek.d_2r.PfBtuIoxDvrbGDL.Lv2AuD6lxiObz_lldDHq6HnEw_irAP1hCH.Dr3KdW33DN2w0X1R75N3f8GXdHinmxXLtYbZNYZEE9K7lk9AGmBWgcTds.XgGVW3gDS5OEwoRat44Ecke8k7ZXoY_2revEbUrD8UpOrGprlPEwVYuAvLoTSZX8WJEWQ_QT2CDjNw0FOwAECzsFJa4hGgUtjCPzG&c1SoYK0a=GBK-4aeKAo74EouxLY.stFwdwvXQQG_hXMGG8gB0Hhe6V2Il9k9c8yiTLqduIXpv2RNt.H.weYXeF5XhV0CR2lATieRmk.cs8.fPhNpfGx7JkG1uacp75kDcmXsNtuKgbzRUHZh8vkj4UEYbPcwIYIOw5gFG_cMi9n1GYq0AXXK9UQn9IsmjCBuI7AOFw.pk91OgjvkJCcg2y0y3yDkGwZPcg5EktfAXi.PjmfaecWg8hodU87q6B3ZuPxhel9K9I3EDBxzCHtZqt_0YFlkJCcK4hLq
```

the problem is with obfuscation and also the nested variables and functions that can keep you out of track for hours if you try to debug it line by line (which I did) and the code makes the characters after `content.jsp?` part one by one and that explains why its about 13000 lines!!

this part `request.send($_9);` should have a body for request because its a `POST` request and `$_9` was always null! it seems there are more protection levels to it as it seems.

- **callBackC:**

well the `callbackC` is apparently a simple function to get `responseText` and show it to user:

```
function callbackC() {
    if (request.readyState == 1) {
        _$c2(document.getElementById(_$Fe("Y3CeXwDYXwq")), '=', _$Fe('vFKyXRUxEYlTW'), _$Fe("kHDxnHOaB3vE5HDxnHOSNMKQGQ6xOHK2z3Kw2Qne7MCm9FKyvhbwNROg"));
    }
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            oldContent[oldContent.length] = request.responseText;
            _$c2(document.getElementById(_$Fe("b3CeXwDYXwq")), '=', _$Fe('EFKyXRUxEYlTW'), request.responseText);
            request = null;
        } else {
            _$c2(document.getElementById(_$Fe("u3CeXwDYXwq")), '=', _$Fe('BFKyXRUxEYlTW'), "<br><br><br><span style=font-size:x-large;color:#215add>服务器未返回数据</span>");
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't quiet get what those _$Xx functions do (because it goes so deep that its out of my patient!) but it seems they simply replaced the `document.getElementById("someThing").innerText="Contents";` with multi layered functions so we can't understand the code easily, and the `request.responseText` is what you need which is HTML code for the table of results.

there is also a **3rd way** which I don't know if you can implement it in your code, but since these functions are in a public scope you can simply override them by redefining these two functions (or replace the functions in the link with your own functions and run them). I tried to get the URL for the request which gave me the link I used in middle of this post, but it didn't worked (I just override the `callBackC` function and get `request.responseURL`) and the link gave me 404 error.

I don't think I said all I got from my observations but I think it's enough for you to know what you are up against if you are not already aware, and I hope I was helpful.

**Reference:**

[XMLHttpRequest: Living Standard — Last Updated 16 August 2021](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. seems it's more complex website! even there's an API which i tried to communicate with it but it' require the values which you described. the API is only shown once you navigate between pages.

Comment: do you think it's possible to call that API ? https://i.imgur.com/IBbYuIa.png it's using a function called `devPage`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη as I understand you want what came from `content.jsp` not `search.jsp` and these parameters in the image you sent are all in the url which changes only when you use `search.jsp` not when you click on those links. and the `devPage` isn't even called on clicking the links or getting back to search results.

Comment: You got me wrongly, if you opened the site , by default it's open page# 1, but if you navigate to page# 2, you will see a call to the API which fetch the desired data

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I was in these situation before, if you can choose how to do this, just open a headless chrome and use multiple tabs or instances, the project will be done by the end of the day :D

Comment: Ok, let's say that I've used selenium, so within each request, i will direct selenium to open the url and then insert the page# and then loop over links to access the desired data. is that what you mean?

Comment: or you meant page by page instead threads as it's hold 15 items per page, so it's will be 2281 / 15 = 1533 page

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη can you send a link of which page are you talking about? my knowledge of Chinese is like a 2 days old child :D

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη if you are talking about the links in the picture of main question, you can open like 15 tabs and in each tab click on one of the links and wait to get the content from server, then read them all in parallel.

Comment: well if there is this much data, you might need to wait lets say 3 seconds for each page content, so you'll need 4599 Seconds or about 1 hour and 20 minutes. these processes are kinda time consuming. you can also open multiple chromes, lets say 10 pages with 15 tabs, this will take only 460 seconds to compelete.